# Inserting editable word document into SQL Server database

Tags: sql

I'm trying to insert a Word document into my SQL Server database, but I'm encountering problems.

Here's my query:

```
INSERT INTO DocumentTemplateCollection (TemplateName, TemplateContent, CreatedBy, CreatedDate)
    SELECT 
        'SomeDocument.docx',
        BulkColumn,
        7,
        GETDATE()
    FROM 
        OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\ADFTemplates\SomeDocument.docx', SINGLE_BLOB) AS DocumentContent;
```

Running this script, I get this error:

> Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\ADFTemplates\SomeDocument.docx" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).

I've tried granting all possible permissions, but the problem persists. Can anyone please tell me what is causing this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Try it in something like c:\temp or a folder in your documents folder.  Possible because it's a folder on the Desktop?

Comment: Is it a local sql-server? Can you share which permissions you have tried to add to the folder/file? Have you tried Mikes approach to move it to a different folder that isn't user specific?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers, I tried moving word docx into another folder, but it didn't help, unfortunately... I opened folders' properties, and in security tab I added sql browser user server permission and allowed it full control for this folder, but it still wouldn't bulk load this document to database...